# Can these two ThreadPoolTaskExecutors affect each other?

Tags: spring, multithreading, tomcat, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I have two `ThreadPoolExecutors`. The first one, initialized in this way one time, in `afterPropertiesSet()`:

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor firstTaskExecutor = null;
```

and then

```
this.firstTaskExecutor= new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
this.firstTaskExecutor.setBeanName("reports");
this.firstTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
this.firstTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(200);
this.firstTaskExecutor
            .setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy());
this.firstTaskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
this.firstTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
```

The second one is wired through a `Bean`, in other controller:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("EMAILS");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

After adding the second one to the code, all tasks performed by the first TaskExecutor seem to be handled by one thread only which means, that the second pool is affecting the first.

Can this be the reason of this?

Comment: How `firstTaskExecutor` is defined?

Comment: I've edited the question. It's a class property: ThreadPoolTaskExecutor firstTaskExecutor = null;

Comment: How do you use `firstTaskExecutor` to execute task. You should post the whole class and its usage